# Linq | Debug and capture returned value from Visual Studio IDE 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Just now I am in this position and thought to spit out.

I am using VS 2013. I have a function call that returns some value. However, I don't store returned value anywhere. Of course, I have an option to add this function in the watch/ or capture outcome in an variable and see return.

Is there any other (hidden) way to know what has returned.

I know it is quite illogical but I am finding a logic that since the program is in debug mode. Does it has any hidden variable or something in pdb or so to find the outcome.

2) On side note, what approach do you use for Linq call as I tend to get "You cannot do this" message from watch window. Of course I can use LinqPad, but I rather prefer to use only one tool as much as possible. So how you are doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the Registers with the the Debug/Windows/Registers window.

For example, I wrote a method that returns 10 without storing it in a variable.
You can see the value 0x0000000A in the memory address before the method returns, and then after the method returns, you can see the value of 0x0000000A (10) in register EAX.

[image]

[image]

It works when returning values from Linq statements also:

[image]

Comment: Awesome very good point. I have an another question on Linq. However you have been thumbs up. I will wait for second point if someone can reflect an idea